# What is the "Cumulative Distribution of the magnitude of the N-dimensional standard gaussian"

Tags: probability-distributions

I am confused by this line from a paper:

"Let $F_1(x)$ be the cumulative distribution of the magnitude of an $n$−dimensional standard Gaussian random
variable and $F_2(x)$ be the cumulative distribution of the magnitude of a random point
in a Euclidean unit ball of radius $r$"

**Can someone explain to me what $F_1(x)$ and $F_2(x)$ is?** Thanks a lot!

The paper is here: http://www.mit.edu/~har/Dikin.pdf (page 9)

I would also really really appreciate it if someone has the time to explain to me how to sample from this Dikin ellipsoid. I think I've fully understood the definitions, but the part about the pseudo-inverse and vector scaling seems confusing.

Thank you!

Edit: I know how to sample points from the $n$-dimensional Gaussian and the $n$-dimensional Euclidean ball. But it seems to me that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are invertible functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a standard $n$ dimensional Gaussian. Then $|X|$ is a random variable, and thus it has a distribution function. The author is saying let $F_1$ be that distribution function, i.e.
$$
F_1(t) = P(|X| \leq t)
$$

Similarly, the Euclidean ball of radius  $r$ has finite volume and so we can consider the uniform measure $\mu$ on the ball (it will be a rescaling of the usual Lebesgue measure). Let $Y$ be a random vector sampled from $\mu$. Then $|Y|$ is a random variable and so it has a distribution function. The author is saying let $F_2$ be that distribution function, i.e.
$$
F_2(t) = P(|Y| \leq t)
$$

Edit: As for invertibilitity, you are correct that they are invertible. This is because $F_1,F_2$ are strictly increasing (a fact that you need to prove).

I suggest you make a separate, more specific, question about any technicalities that stump you in the paper.

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for this! I went to the wikipedia page, and it seems to me that they both involve integrals. I thought the result would be a simple matrix. It is not clear to me how to invert these functions..

Comment: Actually $F_1$ is invertible on $[0,+\infty)$ only and $F_2$ is invertible on $[0,r]$ only.